# Change Wordpress url for newly formed posts or pages

Tags: seo

We have website which uses wordpress and have around 2000 posts. The format for url we choose was http://www.abc.com/xyz/post-title but not we want to change it to http://www.abc.com/abc/post-id/post-title something like stack stackexchange, but since we do have a decent google juice for the existing urls we don't want to loose that. I know some people told me we can use Permanent redirect and the juice will flow with it. but i am not very confident on that.

Is there a way we can customize wordpress so all future posts follow the new url pattern and past pages remains the same.

Any solutions to this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Permanent redirect (which you should do, will not hurt your rankings if it's done properly), you can do like this:

1. Create a custom post type: check [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Example) or install a plugin, like Custom Post Type UI
2. Change the permalink structure for this custom post type ( using a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/) ) to `/custom_post_type/%post_id%/%postname%/`
3. Change your theme to query posts of this new custom type

Comment: So you feel it is okay to redirect around 2000+ posts and pages  individually as there is no way in the url i can identify which needs to be pointed to ?

Comment: You can use a plugin to do that for you automatically. I would recommend Redirection: http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/. But you should test it first on a testing environment. It supports regular expressions, so you can write a regular expression that will match the urls with the old format.

Comment: Thanks. But as i said before, my present links are title based so there is no way i can use regex to redirect them and redirecting each of those 2000 urls doesn't sounds like very tuned approach.